# silex controller setter injection

Tags: dependency-injection, silex

I'm new to PHP/silex.

The issue: cannot inject a dependency into controller.

Controller:

```
class MediaController implements ControllerProviderInterface 
{
   private $serviceManager;

   public function setService($service)
   {
       $this->serviceManager = $service;
   }

   public function getMedia($id)
   {
       $this->serviceManager->getMediaService()->getMedia($id);
   }

   public function connect(Application $app)
   {
       $controllers = $app['controllers_factory'];
       $controllers->get('/id={id}', 'Controllers\Instagram\MediaController::getMedia');
       $controllers->get('/test', 'Controllers\Instagram\MediaController::test');
       return $controllers;
   }
}
```

Injection config file routes.php (this file is called from a config.php file that is also called from app.php which is also called from index.php):

```
function getMediaController($app) {
    $mediaController = new \Controllers\Instagram\MediaController();
    $mediaController->setService(new \Service\InstagramServiceManager());        
    return $mediaController;
}
$app->mount('/media', getMediaController($app));
```

Start the php built in server: php -S localhost:8080 /web

Path to test: /media/id=1

Error: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getMediaService() on a non-object in /home/fernando/projects/php/silex/api_media_location_v2/src/controllers/instagram/MediaController.php on line 41

The line 41 from MediaController.php:

```
$this->serviceManager->getMediaService()->getMedia($id);
```

Any suggestion on how to inject the service into the controller?

Comment: did you read http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/master/services.html ?

Comment: yes, I've also tried this: '$mediaController->setService($app['instagram_service_manager']);' but the result is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: the problem seems to be in the magic method of the controller:

```
__set($propertyName, $propertyValue) {}
```

I just created a custom setter for the service:

```
public function setService($service) {}
```

Also, I found an issue int the connect method from the controller, I have replaced this line:

```
$controllers->get('/test', 'Controllers\Instagram\MediaController::test');
```

for these one:

```
$controllers->get('/test', $this->test());
```